# JavaScript: Key event doesn't fire if selected text is just removed

Tags: javascript

I am applying handlers to the events like keypress, keyup and keydown occuring on a textarea. It works perfectly for every case except if I will select all the text and press `backspace`. The particular assigned function won't be called. If I will press `backspace` once more on the textarea, the function will be called. Here is the code:

```
function myFunc(f) {
    console.log("Fired"); // Is logged when select all and remove
    var h = f.target || f.srcElement || this;
    myFunc2(f); // Doesn't get called when select all and remove
}
function myFunc2(e) {
    var $elem = $(e);
    // do important stuff
};

$textarea.addEventListener("keyup", myFunc);
$textarea.addEventListener("keydown", myFunc);
$textarea.addEventListener("keypress", myFunc);
myFunc({ target: $textarea }); // <-- Call explicitly to manage some stuff
```

**The complete code**

```
function elasticize(a) {
    var b = "overflow" + ("overflowY" in document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].style ? "Y" : ""),
        e = function (h, g, j) {
            if (g.addEventListener) {
                for (var f = 0; f < h.length; f++) {
                    g.addEventListener(h[f], j, 0)
                }
            } else {
                if (g.attachEvent) {
                    for (var f = 0; f < h.length; f++) {
                        g.attachEvent("on" + h[f], j)
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    for (var c = 0; c < a.length; c++) {
        a[c].style[b] = "hidden";
        a[c].__originalRows = a[c].rows;
        var d = function (f) {
            var h = f.target || f.srcElement || this,
                g = h.scrollTop;
                window.resizeBody(h);
            h.scrollTop = 1;
            while (h.scrollTop > 0) {
                var j = h.clientHeight,
                    i = true;
                h.rows++;
                if (h.clientHeight == j) {
                    if (h.style[b]) {
                        h.style[b] = ""
                    }
                    h.scrollTop = g;
                    return
                }
                h.scrollTop = 1
            }
            if (!i) {
                while (h.scrollTop == 0 && h.rows > h.__originalRows) {
                    h.rows--;
                    h.scrollTop = 1
                }
                if (h.scrollTop > 0) {
                    h.rows++
                }
            }
            if (!h.style[b]) {
                h.style[b] = "hidden"
            }
        };
        e(["keypress", "paste", "cut", "keyup", "keydown"], a[c], d);
        d({
            target: a[c]
        })
    }
};
window.resizeBody = function(e) {
    $footer = $(e).parent(),
    $body = $footer.siblings("div.body"),
    footerHeight = $footer.height();

$body.css("margin-bottom", footerHeight + "px").height( function() {
    return window.bodyHeight - footerHeight;
});
};
```

Comment: just bind to the "input" event instead of all those other events; it covers everything you do and more, like mouse pasting, drag and dropped text, kb hotkeys, etc.

Comment: @dandavis No, it didn't work for special keys though. If I press backspace on blank textarea, it won't work at all. BTW, didn't know about that event. Thanks.

Comment: are you saying that the `input`doesn't work for your case?

Comment: @dandavis I am using "input" and "keydown" combination now. My brother just got the solution. The function is called before the height of footer changes. We can either use setTimeout or put our code all the way down so, the function is called when the footer height changes. If you don't know where did footer height and stuff come from then see my complete code. I wanted to change body height based footer height when the height of elastic textarea changed.

Comment: @dandavis My bad. "input" is a great event. It really works for everything. Thanks. Ignore my last comment :D

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. The problem was that my function was being called before the height of footer changed. You will need to either use a Web API namely `setTimeout` or call your function in the end of the parent function. I would recommend doing `setTimeout` with delay of 0 milliseconds so, the important function is called when rest of your code is executed.

```
setTimeout(myFunc2, 0);
```

**Conclusion:**
There is nothing wrong with JavaScript events. You just have to make sure the order of the functions being called is correct.